# Sorting with minimum changeovers between unique patterns

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list of color patterns that I would like to sort with minimum changeovers. It doesn't matter if it starts from the largest or smallest set, and the color order is not important. For example input:

```
Pattern 1 = [blue, white, red, black]

Pattern 2 = [blue, green, white]

Pattern 3 = [blue, green, yellow]

Pattern 4 = [blue, white, red]
```

Output would be:

```
3 -> 2 -> 4 -> 1
```

Starting with pattern 3, we look at what pattern could be done next with the least number of changes, which would be pattern 2 because one color is changed. Then after that would be pattern 4 because again one color is being changed. Finally, pattern 1 because 1 color is being added. Adding and subtracting is considered a changeover.

I have identified the unique patterns but I don't know where to start by sorting.

Comment: what do you mean by minimum changeovers? can you explain how you come to the output?

Comment: Do you want an alphabetical order?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

Comment: Picture a graph where each pattern is a vertex and each edge is weighted by the Levenshtein distance between the two patterns. You are looking for a shortest path between any two vertices.

Comment: A changeover is defined by a *pair* of patterns, so this isn't really a sorting problem. (Or rather, you are sorting pairs of patterns, but not every pair is comparable, so there isn't a total ordering of pairs. A topological sort, though, is closely related to the idea of path-finding in the graph.)

Answer (score 2):

This is a graph problem, namely finding the shortest path between two patterns.

Let each pattern be a vertex in a graph, and the weight of an edge `(p1, p2)` be the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) between the two patterns. For any two patterns, then, you can compute the shortest path between those two patterns (which is not necessarily the single edge connecting them), using (for example) [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm).

For a small graph, you can run Dijkstra's algorithm multiple times for each potential starting and ending point. Depending on the graph, though, you'll probably want to use an algorithm to compute *all* shortest paths using (for example) the [Floyd-Warshall algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm), then selecting the shortest path with valid starting and ending points.

Regarding running times: it will take O(n^2) time to build the graph, *if* you create all possible edges. It's possible that you can do some preprocessing to eliminate those edges that can't possibly be part of the solution.

Dijkstra's algorithm is O(m + n lg n), meaning it is O(n^2) on the complete graph constructed above. With O(n^2) possible pairs, the running time would be O(n^4), which is slower than O(n^3) that Floyd-Warshall's will take on any graph. As you can see, which algorithm you want to use will depend greatly on
how you construct and/or prune your graph, as well as whether you can prune the candidate sets of starting/ending points.

Comment: If I get this right, one needs to check distance from every point to other point and then pick the shortest path among them?

Comment: Correct. I accidentally left out my mention of all-pairs shortest path in the previous version of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if `sorted()` with some `key=` could be applied here. My example is brute-force approach (we are checking all the permutations of patterns for smallest sum of changeovers). Maybe there's fastest algorithm.

```
patterns = [
    ['blue', 'white', 'red', 'black'],
    ['blue', 'green', 'white'],
    ['blue', 'green', 'yellow'],
    ['blue', 'white', 'red']
]

from itertools import permutations

def get_num_changeovers(a, b):
    """ Get number of changeovers from a -> b """
    l = min(len(a), len(b))
    return l - len(set(a) & set(b)) + abs(len(a) - len(b))

cost = float('inf')
current = None
for p in permutations(patterns):
    s = sum(get_num_changeovers(a, b) for a, b in zip(p, p[1:]))
    if s < cost:
        cost = s
        current = p

print('Cost    : ', cost)
print('Patterns: ', current)
```

Prints:

```
Cost    :  3
Patterns:  (['blue', 'white', 'red', 'black'], ['blue', 'white', 'red'], ['blue', 'green', 'white'], ['blue', 'green', 'yellow'])
```